# C# to Vb.NET code convert

Tags: vb.net

below code is `c#`

```
ctx.CreateStreamResponse(stream => new Session(_Sessions, stream).Process(),"video/mp4");
```

and i  need to this code as `VB.NET` code. am converting as below

```
ctx.CreateStreamResponse(Function(stream) New Session(_Sessions, stream).Process(), "video/mp4")
```

But getting error

> overload resolution failed because no accessible
>   "CreateStreamResponse" can be called with these arguments.

`CreateStreamResponse` needs 2 parameters

1. Stream (as my sample Function(stream) New Session(_Sessions, stream).Process())
2. content type (as my sample  "video/mp4")

Anyone can help me, please

Comment: Well, there seems to be something wrong with the Process() function.  Perhaps it is missing the `As` keyword to declare its return type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue seems to be that the method which you pass into `CreateStreamResponse` should be a `Sub` not a `Function`. i.e:

```
ctx.CreateStreamResponse(Sub(stream) New Session(_Sessions, stream).Process(), "video/mp4")
```

[**CreateStreamResponse**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782275(v=vs.110).aspx)  takes an `Action(Of Stream)` delegate as the first argument and a contentType of `String` as the second argument.

Thus you need to use `Sub` rather than a `Function` as in this case an `Action` delegate can only encapsulate methods that return *void* (sub procedures). Also, ensure that the `Process` method being invoked is also a Sub procedure.

If the problem persists then as suggested by Microsoft docs:

> 1. Review all the overloads for the method and determine which one you
>      want to call.
> 2. In your calling statement, make the data types of the arguments
>      match the data types of the parameters defined for the desired
>      overload. You might have to use the CType Function to convert one or
>      more data types to the defined types.

for more information see **[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30521)**